# when defining continuous operators on distributions, why does the adjoint operator need to be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Here is how folland introduces the construction of continuous operators on distributions:

[image: p284 of folland]

I understand that the adjoint/equality thing is needed so that the constructed operator is an extension of the original operator.

However, I'm confused about the "continuity of $T'$ guaranteeing continuity of $T$." My question:

> For continuity of $T$, why do we need continuity or linearity of $T'$?

To me, it seems that continuity of $T$ only requires that the adjoint $T'$ be a (set) map of the space of test functions $C_c^\infty$ into itself, since if $F_j \to F$ as distributions (ie pointwise on test functions, because weak* topology)

$$ \langle TF_j, \phi \rangle
    := \langle F_j, T' \phi \rangle
    \to \langle F, T' \phi \rangle
    =: \langle TF, \phi \rangle.   
$$

Actually, based on the above, it seems you could just define a continuous operator $T$ on $D'$ if you have such a set map $T'$.

What am I missing here? I haven't actually checked it, but I bet linearity of $T$ requires linearity of $T'$ was linear...but for continuity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which book by Folland did you read this?

I agree with you that continuity of $T'$ seems not be needed for continuity of $T$ extended to $\mathcal{D}'.$ However, I think that it is needed for $TF$ to be a distribution, i.e. for $TF$ to be continuous:

Let $\varphi_j \to \varphi$ in $C_c^\infty$ and assume that $T'$ is continuous. Then, 
$
\langle TF, \varphi_j \rangle
= \langle F, T'\varphi_j \rangle
\to \langle F, T'\varphi \rangle
= \langle TF, \varphi \rangle
,$
i.e. $TF$ is continuous.

Comment: ahh you're totally right!
and this is page 284 of [folland's "real analysis: modern techniques and their applications"](https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Modern-Techniques-Applications/dp/0471317160)

Comment: @sgtswordfish. I need to check my copy when I get home later today.

Comment: I cannot find that comment in my copy of the book, which must be the first edition. ([Image](https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1400440128l/4819828.jpg) and [PDF on Scribd](https://www.scribd.com/document/68755887/Folland-Real-Analysis-Modern-Techniques-and-Their-Wiley))

Comment: ahhh interesting ok. i think mine is definitely one of the earlier ones, since i have to use both of the erratas that folland put out

Comment: I sent an email to Prof. Folland asking him if we miss something, if we misunderstand what he writes, or if this is an actual error in the book.

Comment: Gerald Folland has now answered my question:
"You're right: the place where the continuity of T' is really needed is in guaranteeing that the formula <TF, phi> = <F, T'phi> defines TF as a distribution."

Comment: awesome, sounds good! thanks